# Cambiar Formatos

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Como le puedo cambiar el formato a un DateTimePicker y a un Label

Quisiera que el DateTimePicker muestre un formato dd/mm/yyyy h:mm
Y que el Label tenga un formato de moneda.

¿Como podría hacer?

Comment: En que lo haces? web, xamarin o escritorio?

Comment: @RamiroBarone es de escritorio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te servirá para mostrar la fecha y la hora en el formato que elijas:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
```

También puedes sobreescribir los valores por defecto del `DateTimePicker`:

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm";
```

Para el `label` le asignas el valor pasándolo a `string` con el formato "Cx" dónde la x es el número de decimales a mostrar, en el ejemplo el valor es de 100.10:

```
double valor = 100.10;
label1.Text = valor.ToString("C2");
```

También

```
label1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", valor);
```

O con la cultura:

```
label1.Text = valor.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

También puedes forzar la cultura en que se muestra la moneda:

```
label1.Text = valor.ToString("C2", new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
```

Comment: El de la fecha me funciono gracias, pero en el `labe` me sale error en el `ToString` me dice ninguna carga para el metodoto ToString toma 2 argumentos

Comment: Qué valor le estás pasando? y qué tipo de datos es el valor?

Comment: yo le paso unos datos desde otro formulario, los datos los tengo como entero

Comment: Prueba con `label1.Text = valor.ToString("C2");`

Comment: Me sigue dando error en el ToString dice `Ninguna sobre carga para el método ToString toma 1 argumentos `

Comment: Última opción: `label1.Text = String.Format("{2:C}", valor);`

Comment: Nada, no me ha funcionado un pregunta ¿En el diseñador no se puede modificar para que haga esa función?

Comment: Antes me equivoqué, puse un 2 cuando debería ser un 0: `label1.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", valor);`

Comment: disculpa yo a ese label le mando valores de dos formas y una de esa es desde una tabla carga ¿Como puedo agregarle ese codigo a esta linea `total.Text = frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();`?

Comment: **PD:**lo intente de esta forma pero no me funciona `total.Text = String.Format("{0:C}",frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());`

Comment: Prueba con `total.Text = String.Format("{0:C}",frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);` o bien con `total.Text = String.Format("{0:C}",(double)frm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);`

Comment: Listo, me funciono la primera opción, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar un parametro en la propiedad`CustomFormat` y `Format`

```
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm";
   dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```